# How to operate on the table many to many EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with ASP.NET MVC and I am using Entity Framework. While generating my database which has been created by DataBase First I got this relation which is shown below. My question is: how can I assign a role for a particular patient?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This slightly depends on how your project is structured, and any design patterns you're using, but the below code should point you in the right direction.

```
// query the DB for existing patient/role
var dbContext = new MyDbContext()
var patient = dbContext.Set<Patient>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.PatientID = patientId); 
var role = dbContext.Set<Role>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleID = roleId); 

patient.Roles.Add(role);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**

Or something like this for a new instance of a patient...

```
var newPatient = new Patient {
                            Name = "NameHere"
                             ....
                            };

newPatient.Roles.Add(role);
dbContext.Entry(newPatient).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thx for answer :) i have problems but I just familiarize you with operations. Im working on registration and I would like to add roles("user") for the patient but i dont know how to recieve PatientID if he doesn't exist in base yet. Do you have any idea??
Greatings

Comment: @rejentt I've updated the answer to cover your question, hopefully this helps